# Moving a Azure Cloud Service (Classic) to a new subscription

Tags: azure

When trying to a Classic Service to a new subscription i encounter an error.
When following MS Docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/classic-model-move-limitations - There seems to be limitations as the service is classic.

It seems the only way to move the subscription is by using REST API. However i have absolutetly no experience with REST API, is there any other way to move the Service to a new subscription not involving REST API

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this yourself is through the rest API. If you have a support contract you can raise a request and see if they can do something from their end but otherwise the rest API is the only option.

Doing this through the rest API should be fairly straightforward. You can use the Azure CLI [Rest command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404) to send REST API calls, avoiding having to deal with authentication headers etc. Then it is just a case of feeding it the subscription ID you want to move. As the doc states, you must move all resources in the subscription.

The other option is to rebuild your environment in the new sub (ideally using non-classic resources as these will be deprecated) and then move your traffic.

Comment: Dear Sam. Appreciate your reply with many thanks. I will try to investigate REST commands further. Have a great day onwards!